# Difference between appName.app and appName.app.dsYM file of iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, react-native-ios

Can anyone explain to me what is the difference between appName.app and appName.app.dsYM file and which file submit on the AppStore?
As I am checking it in my finder both file has a different size so I am confused which one will be used by Apple?

Thank you.

[image: This is the image for both files.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.app file is an iOS application and .dSYM is debug symbol file which is used to trace the crash log and used to convert the crash log to human readable form.

You need to submit **`.ipa`** file to App Store.

For that you need to do following....

- Select **"Generic iOS Device"**
- Change the app version or build number, if required
- Go to **Product -> Archive**
- Once successfully archived you will see the organiser window. You will see the Archive list.
- You need to select the archive that you have just done.(by default it will be selected)
- If you want upload iOS app directly via XCODE then select **Distribute App -> App Store Connect-> Upload**. and follow the instruction. The app will be uploaded on App Store connect.
- If you want to manually upload app (like using Transporter App, etc.) the you need to select **Distribute App -> App Store Connect-> Export** option. The `.ipa` file will be exported after successful validation pass. That *`.ipa`* file you need to upload to App Store Connect.